# In Ubuntu 14.04 eclipse luna, eclipse juno and android studio is crashing every time?

Tags: 14.04, android, eclipse, android-studio

In my ubuntu 14.04 nothing is working here i'm using android studio, whenever i'm starting my android studio this error i am getting.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=6793, tid=140194392291072
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_76-13)build.7.0_76-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.76-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit
# http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

I can remember getting the same error a few months ago. Have you already tried to un- and reinstall Java? Removing Oracle JDK 7 and switching to Java 8 did it for me. You can try to follow these instructions:

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Java/Installation/Oracle_Java/Java_8

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have changed java7 to java8 but again my android studio is crashing.
Do you have any other solution for that.

Comment: I guess you're running 64-Bit Ubuntu? Make sure that Android Studio does also. Another hint: Check if the alternatives system has been updated to the new Java version. On console "java -version" will tell you.

Comment: Well that makes sense, thanks for advice David!